# Is the close vote on my question regarding hugo justified?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

First thing first, it is my understanding that Superuser is for questions about computer software. Therefore I have posted a question regarding the use of [`hugo`, which is static site generation tool](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo).

[My hugo question](https://superuser.com/questions/1267831/unable-to-generate-a-tag-page) is  not a programming question because no programming is involved. It is not a server infrastructure question either because no server side issue is involved in this case. Therefore, in my opinion, the question does not belong to Stackoverflow and Serverfault.

This leads me to believe Superuser is the most suitable site to solicit answers from the Stackexchange community.

However a fellow superuser user has a different opinion. Here is link to his comment: [Unable to generate a tag page](https://superuser.com/questions/1267831/unable-to-generate-a-tag-page?noredirect=1#comment1867783_1267831) , in which he asserted:

> this question does not even belong on SuperUser

I presume whoever casted the close vote (so far 1) thinks this way.

I appreciate the superuser community and it has been very helpful to me when I look for answers and solutions. So I am just seeking clarification here.

My question is: what qualify a piece of software to **belong** to Superuser? To me `hugo` is as much a software tool as `vim`. I do not think the close vote  is justified.

Comment: I don't think it is off-topic but I do think it is extremely unclear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe a you could read the question aloud to yourself and see if it makes sense?

Comment: Given the formatting of your question it makes it unclear as to whether you are asking about how to write code to make Hugo work or if you have a problem with Hugo itself. The former (coding) would be off-topic here while the latter would be on-topic.

Comment: Specifically you start out with a block of random code. This sets the tone for how people read the rest of your question. With poor cropping on your pictures it is also hard to see where the image ends and your question looks jumbled and is difficult to read.

Comment: I started the question with a section of config file. The thing is for people who know Hugo, it should be clear it is a configuration question.

Comment: I kinda chose not to instaclose this cause its... kinda in a funny place - and SU's probably the 'closest' to on topic site to me. Webapps typically isn't for stuff you run yourself either. THe question *could* be clearer and it never hurts to start with some background information

Comment: @AnthonyKong, there are a couple of purposes for tags, but you're right about using them to attract people who are familiar with the subject.  Apply that logic to the fact that you created the tag.  In the entire history of the site, there have been only 3 questions about the Hugo software, and two of those are yours.  This is the first one that was sufficiently Hugo-centric to even warrant a tag.  Only two people have ever answered any Hugo-related question and the tag has no followers.  So while it's on-topic, the site is not a good resource because there are almost no experts to attract.

Answer (score 1):

Every close vote has a justification, otherwise it would not have been cast. Even "I did not mean to click that" is a justification.

The mass of the Community means that there must be 5 such justifications made or asserted before the question is actually closed, and even then the design of SuperUser is not for closed questions to remain closed. Instead, closure is a Time Out to motivate the asker to improve the question so that it can be reopened and then answered.

For all the reasons given in the comments both on the original post and here your question:

- is acceptable and on-topic
- is unlikely to get much attention
- can be improved (which might improve its chances)